# Why is it easier to close a door if you're pushing further from the hinges

Tags: torque

It's much harder to closer a door if you push near its hinges as opposed to pushing at the edge of the door. I understand that this is because the torque is calculated by $r \times F$, but I'm trying to get a feel for **why** the distance from the rotation axis matters. How does the door (or long rod) that I'm trying to turn know how far I am away from the rotation axis?

If I peel everything back, I'm just pushing some atoms in the door, which then pull neighbouring atoms along for the ride etc..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a body rotate faster if force is applied away from the pivot?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/623855/why-does-a-body-rotate-faster-if-force-is-applied-away-from-the-pivot)

Comment: Conservation of energy. Levers are normally thought of as being applied to a mass. or linear force. Take that linear momentum and stick it at the end of a lever as if it were a mass or force. The atoms are going along for the ride, but they're not all moving with the same amount of energy. The atoms farther from the hinge move a lot faster and a lot farther for the same angular swing in the door.

Answer (score 1):

It takes the same amount of *energy* to close the door no matter where you push on it. But when you push farther away from the hinges, you spread out that energy transfer over a longer distance (the same angular distance, but a longer actual distance). Since energy transfer through work is equivalent to force integrated over distance, a longer distance requires a smaller average force. Your arm interprets things in terms of forces, so it feels easier to close a door at a longer distance from the hinges.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the door accelerates the same way in both cases, this is simply a matter of work done -- if you push closer to the hinge, you apply a stronger force over a shorter distance. If you push further away from the hinge, you apply a weaker force over a longer distance. It's the same principles that pulleys or inclined planes use.